# Activate View for header delegate for specific section in single table

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am developing an application in which I need header to customize and add my own button just for single section. I googled and done some code where I am able to add button, but I am facing two issue.

1. Titles of other's section is not showing.
2. Button not show properly because of tableview scroll size same after adding button.
   Here is what I am doing.

   ```
   - (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

       UIView * headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 40)] autorelease];
       [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
   if(section==2){
       float width = tableView.bounds.size.width;
       int fontSize = 18;
       int padding = 10;

       UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(padding, 2, width - padding, fontSize)];
       label.text = @"Texto";
       label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
       label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
       label.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
       label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,1);
       label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize];

       [headerView addSubview:label];

       UIButton * registerButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
       [registerButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"P_register_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [registerButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 150)];
       [headerView addSubview:registerButton];


       return headerView;
   }
       return headerView;

   }
   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

   return 3;
   }

    - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   if(section==0)
       return @"Registration";
   else if(section==1)
       return @"Player Detail";
   return nil;
   }
   ```

Here is Image of my out put in which Texto text show but button is under that area where the end limit of table view scroll height and also section 0 and 1 title is not showing I also block code for first and second section in viewforheaderinsection. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The other header names don't appear because the viewForHeader method only answers for section 2.  Once implemented, the datasource expects that method to be the authority on all headers.  Just add some else logic for the other sections....

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    UIView * headerView;
    UILabel *label;

    if (section==2) {
        headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 40)] autorelease];
        [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        // and so on
        return headerView;

    } else if (section == 0) {
        label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,tableView.bounds.size.width, 44)] autorelease];
        label.text = @"Section 0 Title";
        return label;
    } else .. and so on
```

The header answered by this method looks to be 40px high (see initWithFrame), but the button being added is 150px high (see setFrame: for the button).  That's the likely the root cause of the button issue.  Try implementing:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return (section == 2)? 150.0 : UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. For first answer what should be logic just give me hint. And for second I increase height to 200 but same happen, I think it has some specific height.